# How to get a list of objects using several model relationships in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

**I would like to get a list of UserProfile of a user's followers**

I have the following models :

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True, db_index=True)
#   ...

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#   ...

class UserFollow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="follow_follower", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="follow_following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
#   ...
```

How can I accomplish this while optimizing database queries ?

> I use rest framework.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, given a `username` of a user (say user1), you want to retrieve all the `userprofiles` from the users following user1, right?

Whereas I do not think this is possible with a one-liner, I think the following should to the trick:

```
followers = UserFollow.objects.filter(following__username=username).values('follower')
follower_profiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__in=followers)
```

Comment: I would like to have something almost like that :
`follower_profiles = User.objects.get(username=username).follow_following.all().follower.profile`

Answer (score 0):

I saw your message, you want  `: follower_profiles = User.objects.get(username=username).follow_following.all().follower.profile`

You should want this.

```py
query_set = User.objects.get(username='username').follow_follower.select_related('follower__profile').all().follower.profile

for query in query_set.all():
    print(query.follower.user)  #  Here is the model for UserProfile.
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not work with me.
Here is the error I get: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'follower'`

Comment: I have updated, you can try it.